# SQL Order by ... ASC

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a problem with a SQL query. I wish to have my results sorted in the ascending order but the problem is that the DB sort me the results only according to the first figure, whereas logically, 2 should be before 19 for example.

Here's my request and a screenshot of the result which does not go at all :

```
SELECT * FROM mail WHERE titre LIKE '%$mot%' ORDER BY mail.titre ASC
```

[image: Very bad sort...]

What I want is all the results sorted like this : 1 2 3 4 5 ... 101 102 103 ... 8845 8850 ... and so on.

Would you have an idea to this problem?

Regards.

Comment: I guess you cut away the part with sensible data, but it seems that your records are strings with data separated by a pipe charachter. You have first to take only the part before the first pipe and converti it to int, or just find the position "i" of the pipe and concatenate n-i zeroes before the string and order alphabetically, where "n" is big enough to produce a resulting string larger than any value you can have in first column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you column is decalred as `char`. So the DBMS is sorting by string value. You have to convert your values to int in the sort clause.

```
SELECT * FROM mail WHERE titre LIKE '%$mot%' ORDER BY convert(mail.titre, unsigned integer) ASC
```

Comment: Perfect, it works correctly, thanks a lot! I got it! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Won't do. You have string/char[] column, and order you are looking for works on numbers only.
You need to convert this column to numbers, if it's possible.

You can use cast:

```
CAST(mail.titre,int)
```

Examples are here:
[Converting text column to integer in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654433/converting-text-column-to-integer-in-mysql)

Comment: Good idea, @Jens find the perfect query, like as all you've been saying you and Robert ! :D

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see the field is a varchar/text... So to sort them correctly you would have to cast the field (if possible)

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM mail WHERE titre LIKE '%$mot%' ORDER BY CAST(mail.titre AS int) ASC
```